# BibDesk: dismiss specific keywords from view

Tags: bibdesk

First of all, if this shouldn't be the right forum for this, please let me know.

So assume I have labeled my entries in BibDesk with keywords named "foo", "foo2", "bar" and "bar2".

If I open the program I see all entries and on the left I can filter for a single specific keyword. Is there an option where I can dismiss specific keywords from the view, so that entries labeled with these keywords are not shown any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field groups in the left sidebar in BibDesk automatically list all the values (items) in the relevant BibTeX field. There is no way to prevent a value from being listed there unless you delete all instances of the value in the database.

If you only want to show in the sidebar certain field values that you choose, you can hide the field groups by clicking "Hide" (or remove them from view entirely by alt-clicking on the field name at the top and selecting "Remove Group"), and instead you can create smart groups using your chosen field values as the search criteria for the smart groups.

Alternatively, you could also create an entirely new field and put only certain values in that field, and display the field groups for that field in the sidebar.